# Tikz forest help

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, forest

I am working to create [image: THIS] but cannot add the red box. There are more other modifications I am working to include: arrows instead of lines, a caption, and more space so the boxes are not cut. Here is my code so far!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\footnotesize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
}
[Parent
        [Child2
            [Child21]
            [Child22]           
            [Child23,name=Child23]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\footnotesize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
}
[Parent,name=Parent
        [Child2
            [Child21]
            [Child22]           
            [Child23,name=Child23]]]]
\node[right=2cm of Parent,draw, minimum width=14em, minimum
height=10ex,red](Stepfather){};         
\draw[red] (Stepfather) -- (Parent);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method which adds the node as part of the tree, using a fake root. For complex cases, this approach tends to be easier, although it certainly isn't necessary here.

I recommend updating your code to use Forest's `edges` library, however, and more flexible anchor specifications. `arrows.meta` can be used to add fancy arrow tips to your edges.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw=black,
    align=center,
    l sep'=4ex,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    font=\footnotesize, 
    minimum width=14em, 
    minimum height=10ex,
    edge+={-Latex},
  }
  [, coordinate
    [Parent, no edge
      [Child2
        [Child21]
        [Child22]           
        [Child23]]]
      [, draw=red, before computing xy={s'+=10mm}, edge+={red}, edge path'={(!s) -- ()}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified tree]

Comment: I agree that one can learn more from your code. (+1 ;-)

Comment: @marmot I don't know about *more*, but sometimes the `tikz` and relative name thing is easier. (Especially, you can make styles this way to avoid replicating code for similar constructions each time.)